# Adding new custom properties in Kafka Connect

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to add new custom **Kafka Converter** which is a modification of **JsonConverterConfig** in **connect-json**. I am trying to add some new custom property say **"schemas.modifications.enable"** in the converter which extends JsonConverterConfig. But Kafka connect is not able to find details about the converter.
My code Snippet :

```
public class ModifiedJsonConfig extends JsonConverterConfig {

public static final String SCHEMAS_MODIFY_CONFIG = "schemas.modifications.enable";
public static final boolean SCHEMAS_MODIFY_CONFIG_DEFAULT = true;
private static final String SCHEMAS_MODIFY_CONFIG_DOC = "The maximum number of schemas that can be cached in this converter instance.";
private static final String SCHEMAS_MODIFY_CONFIG_DISPLAY = "Schema Cache Size";


private final static ConfigDef CONFIG;

static {
    String group = "Schemas-modification";
    int orderInGroup = 0;
    CONFIG = ConverterConfig.newConfigDef();
    CONFIG.define(SCHEMAS_MODIFY_CONFIG, Type.BOOLEAN, SCHEMAS_MODIFY_CONFIG_DEFAULT, Importance.HIGH, SCHEMAS_MODIFY_CONFIG_DOC, group,
            orderInGroup++, Width.MEDIUM, SCHEMAS_MODIFY_CONFIG_DISPLAY);
}

public static ConfigDef configDef() {
    return CONFIG;
}

public ModifiedJsonConfig(Map<String, ?> props) {
    super(props);
}

public boolean schemasModified() {
    return getBoolean(SCHEMAS_MODIFY_CONFIG);
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error here :

> ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:83)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Unknown configuration 'schemas.modifications.enable'

But I have defined this configuration. It would be really helpful if you can help me set a custom converter property here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of connect are you using? Are you aware of this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6981

Comment: Yeah. I stumbled upon the issue while trying to resolve it. But I am using Kafka 2.1.1 and I think its resolved since Kafka 2.0.0.

Comment: @james.bondu, Have implement whole `Converter` or only add `ModifiedJsonConfig`? Please add also more details: kafka-connect configuration, eventually sample Connector configuration, a little bit more of stack trace, etc.

Comment: Agreed. It's not clear how your Converter is using that config class